# Django no reverse match for view details

Tags: django, django-views

im stuck on show details for object, no matter i do (following all guides on internet )
still getting reverse not match error

`views.py`

```
def val_details(request, id):

    val = Validator.objects.get(id=id)
    print(f'vali: {val}')

    context = dict(val=val)

    return render(request, 'users/val_details.html', context)
```

`print(f'vali: {val}')`   printing `vali: Validator object (14)`

`html`

```
<button class="btn btn-warning " href="{% url 'val-details' val.id %}">detals</button>
```

`urls.py`

```
path('dashboard/validator/<int:id>/', user_views.val_details, name='val-details'),
```

`models.py`

```
class Validator(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __int__(self):
        return self.id
```

error
`django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'val-details' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['users/validator/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$']`

`profile view`

```
def profile(request):

    valid = Validator.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    valid_count = valid.count()

    context = {
        'valid': valid,
        'valid_count': valid_count,
    }
    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

and `urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from users import views as user_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('dashboard/', user_views.profile, name='dashboard'),
    path('dashboard/validator/<int:id>/', user_views.val_details, name='val-details'),
```

]

Comment: Don't use ```id```. It is a python built-in function. Where is ```val_details.html``` ?

Comment: @Ram, is that what you mean ?

`def val_details(request, id):

    val = Validator.objects.get(id=id)`

if yes, then still the same :(

Comment: Not the view. I mean the Template - ```val_details.html``` . Your ```val_details``` view is rendering this template. Also add relevant ```views``` and ```urls``` to the question.

Comment: `val_details.html` is in the same app if you asked for this

Comment: You get this ```NoReverseMatch``` error when Django is unable to find matching ```url``` pattern. Please provide your complete url patterns

Comment: @Ram , i have added relevant views and urls

Answer (score 1):

this is the typical error message if in your

```
<button class="btn btn-warning " href="{% url 'val-details' val.id %}">detals</button>
```

val.id is either NULL or empty.

Please check where you assign it.

Comment: can you point me where to look to check this ?

Comment: for example go backwards ...first step:  {{ val.id }}     before the <button ....

Comment: ok, so looks like href="{% url 'val-details' `val.id` %}" is pointing to urls `path('dashboard/validator/<int:id>/', user_views.val_details, name='val-details'),` and then to view, if im correct

Comment: yes, but please check "backwards" why val.id is empty -> error message when processing path(...)

Comment: thx for pushing me to use more of my brain :) , that was so small issue and the answer was on front of me . 
 <button class="btn btn-warning " href="{% url 'val-details' `v.id` %}">detals</button> was the answer in my case. `{% for v in valid %}` in my profile template.  thank you